# Populate data when element created using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, combobox

I created a dynamic element when the user clicks a button. And the element is Combobox. 
The data in the Combobox I took from the database. And I took it using Ajax.

But, I have a problem when putting the data into the dynamic Combobox.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var berkasNumber = 5;

        $("#tambah_field_berkas").click(function() {
            var strField = "<div class='form-inline'><div class='form-group'><select name='jenis_berkas[]' id='berkas' class='form-control'><option value='' class='form-control'>Pilih Berkas</option></select></div><div class='form-group'><input type='text' name='biaya[]' class='form-control' placeholder='Biaya' /></div><div class='form-group'><input type='text' name='lokasi[]' class='form-control' placeholder='Lokasi' /></div>&nbsp;&nbsp;<div class='form-group'><a onclick='hapus()' id='remove_field_berkas'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove red' style='cursor:pointer;' title='Remove'></span></a></div></div>";

            if (counter <= berkasNumber) {
                // Populate combobox value
                $.ajax({
                    url : 'helper_berkas.php',
                    dataType : 'json',
                    success : function(data) {
                        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            //console.log(data[i].nama_berkas);
                            $("#berkas").append('<option>'+ data[i].nama_berkas +'</option>')
                        }
                    }
                });

                $("#field-berkas").append(strField);
            }

            counter++;
        });
    });
```

In the above code just adds to the existing data on the second Combobox (Second click trigger).

Any solutions? Thank you very much.

Comment: Multiple elements with the same id...

Comment: @epascarello yes, how to handle that?

Comment: One way is to append the counter to the ID. Another is to use a class and DOM traversal functions.

Comment: I use this but not work, `$("#berkas" + counter).append('<option>'+ data[i].nama_berkas +'</option>');`